# Laravel Nova Custom tools, fields, filters HOT RELOAD?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Laravel nova with mix reaches it limits when it becomes about hot reloading

> npm run hot

we have to work with

> npm run watch

which we have to refresh the page with each code modifications

which is so bad experience when styling with css etc...

i ended up with just migrating from MIX to VITE but anyhow nova built different

running npm run hot inside nova-components folder wont give u the ability to hot reload !

tried to migrate from mix to vite, and with no vail